# My groupbox is not showing

Tags: c#

I have created many groupbox staked one on top of the other and made them to be invisible however ,if i call the first group box it shows but if i call the other groupboxes they will not show

```
     private void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         groupBox1.Show();// is showing
      }

     private void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             groupBox2.Show();// is  not showing 
        }
```

The second related problem is that if i try an if statement it the selected if statement shows nothing at all

```
     private void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         if (comboBoxType.Text == "Car" && comboBoxName.Text == "BMW"
          " && radioButtonBlack.Checked){

          if (checkBoxTwoseater.Checked || radioButtonLeather.Checked ||  
                   radioButtonBooster.Checked ){
             groupBox1.show}
```

I cannot insert an image because i am new

Answer (score 0):

Well, you said they are all on top of each other, so what is likely happening is the second call works just fine, but it is actually appearing *behind* the first one.

What you need to write is:

```
 private void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    groupBox1.Show();// is showing
 }

 private void buttonFinish2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     groupBox1.Hide();
     groupBox2.Show();// is showing now!
 }
```

Note that this code is odd, since both methods appear to be named the same. I changed that to make "compilable" code, but you should check yours to make sure that it isn't causing a problem.

`Show` just sets the `Visible` property to true, it does not affect the Z-Order (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

The second problem will require you stepping through the code with a debugger and checking all your conditions, you haven't given enough information for us to help.

Comment: my apologies but it is only one buttton Finish i made.

Comment: @user3728117 you still can't have two click functions, so you might want to solve that problem first. Can you post the working/compilable code?

Comment: here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i0j5wozdwkjso7o/AADzPSP0xnw0-FBMTTsDxy-ra

Comment: That just looks like a suo and sln file. I'm not going to download and debug your code for you, can you post a working sample in your question instead?